# How to drop materialized view logs if underlying log table ($MLOG_...) is dropped?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, materialized-view

In an attempt to work around another problem, I have mistakenly dropped the underlying tables for a materialized view log, and now I can neither drop that log nor the MV relating to it. Our DBA says it's because those tables were manually dropped. 
Is there a way of either forcing the logs to be dropped in the absence of those tables or else recreate those tables?

Version Information:

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since there are no responses here.

I don't know if the problem was to do with the underlying tables or something else, we bounced the instance anyway. I also recreated the views using a SQL script (just create one for another table and use it as a template) and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: thanks for taking things into your own hands and sharing your solution